# How to prevent duplicate records in salesforce using validation Rule?

Tags: validation-rule, duplicate-management

I want to prevent duplicate records of an object in Salesforce. I know how to do it by writing a trigger,but some one told me it can be possible by validation rule also. 
Can anyone help me how to avoid duplicate records using validation rule ?

Comment: there is an idea exchange post for same https://success.salesforce.com/ideaView?id=08730000000BpwkAAC .  Can't you just use unique checkbox on field?

Answer (score 2):

Salesforce implemented new functionality to spot the duplicate, using [Matching rules](https://help.salesforce.com/apex/HTViewHelpDoc?id=matching_rules_overview.htm&language=en_US) and [Duplicate rules](https://help.salesforce.com/apex/HTViewHelpDoc?id=duplicate_rules_create.htm&language=en_US).

You don't have to replicate the functionality with custom workflow rules, unique fields, triggers etc. Plus it has the ability to do fuzzy matching as well as exact matching.

Answer (score 0):

You can also do it with a unique field and workflow rule ( field update ).